# Have a better solution for this math computing? (Java)

Tags: java, math

I have a Java program that I must do for homework, and here's the formula that I must use: [picture of formula](https://it.inf.unideb.hu/honlap/prog2/201112-1-pti-gyakorlo-1?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=eq_001.png). Sorry, I am not a native English speaker, and I don't know  the name of this formula.

I've written this solution:

```
/* Check: 
 * if: j<=3:
 * 
 * 1/1+sqrt2=0,414213562
 * 1/sqrt2+sqrt3=0,317837245
 * 1/sqrt3+sqrt4=0,267949192
 *      res= 0,9999999 =~1.0
 */
double sum = 0;
for (int j = 2; j <= 624; j++) 
{
    sum += 1 / ((Math.sqrt(j) + Math.sqrt(j + 1)));
}
double res = 0;
res = (double)1 / (1 + Math.sqrt(2)) + sum;

System.out.println("Result is: "  + res);
```

I've checked the program for `j=2` to `j=3`, and it gave the right result (around 1.0). So I think it is working well. But, when I've tried up to `j<=624`, my result is: `24.000000000000014`

**1.** How can I make the result will be 24.0 and not 24.000000000014 in my program?

**2.** Is there a better solution / source code for this math formula? What is this formula's name in english?

Comment: +1 for listing it as homework, although in the future please use the homework tag.

Comment: @blaces: Your link is giving me security errors: "The server's certificate did not match its hostname."  Your computer admin people need to fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to the world of floating-point computation. Unless you can rewrite your formula using algebra in a way that uses fewer terms or converges more rapidly, you're out of luck -- floating-point computation is never exact and accumulates errors, as you can see from your example.

(a specific hint in this case: your terms are of the form X<sub>k</sub> = 1 / (sqrt(k) + sqrt(k+1)). Try multiplying numerator and denominator by sqrt(k+1) - sqrt(k))

Comment: I understand. And Thank you for multiplying numerator and denominator

Answer (score 0):

1st question: Use Math.round(double) function which returns the closest integer of the double.

You can also use Math.floor(double) to get the closest integer that is less than the double 
or math.ceil(double) which returns the closest integer that is more than the double.

Comment: The point isn't to return an integer, the point is to return a result that is as close as possible to what's expected. If you run the series to  623 instead of 624, you don't get an integer result.

Answer (score 0):

For java calculations, you must use BigDecimal.

Comment: -1: BigDecimal does not have a built-in sqrt() operation; how is it supposed to know how many decimal places to use?

Comment: see this post for srt on BigDecimal :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384919/are-there-libraries-for-square-root-over-bigdecimal ; in all cases using doubles in loops even for additions can give precision loss, it's not the case with BigDecimals

Comment: I have to disagree with your response comment. Unless BigDecimal can literally handle infinite precision, you are wrong.

If so, please print out sqrt(2) as a BigDecimal and let me know how long it took your computer to print it. :P.

Comment: @rmk: huh? Last I checked, square roots often yield irrational numbers, and when you approximate them with BigDecimal (not possible to give an exact representation of irrationals with a finite decimal), even if the precision loss is reduced, you still have a source of error. I'll remove my downvote if you can edit your post for useful advice on how to use BigDecimal in a way that makes sense.

Comment: It's impossible to represent an irrational number exactly using a double or BigDecimal, but BigDecimal has a lower precision loss, which might be useful. I think the best solution is to rewrite the formula using algebra, as suggested in another answer, but, barring that, BigDecimal helps.

Comment: That's I wanted to say. Indeed we cannot have the exact representation of an irrational number , that's impossible. But more generally double calculations will often result in precision loss, whereas we can have more precise results with BigDecimals, even no precision loss at all in some cases.