# Increase Accuracy with Java BigDecimal

Tags: java, math

**Appetizer**

```
R = new BigDecimal(2.79E+00);
Dxm3d = new BigDecimal(3.99E-04);
Wmd = new BigDecimal(2.39E-03);
x = new BigDecimal(3.2);
t = new BigDecimal(365);
```

**Below is the formula**

These values J263 is the excel ballots representing my variables.

- J253 value: 2,39E-03 is the Wmd
- J254 value: 3,99E-04 is the Dxm3d
- J 255 value: 2,79E00 is the R
- I259: 365 is the t
- J263 value: 3.2 is the x

[image]

[image]

```
BigDecimal segundoTermo = (R.multiply(x).subtract(Wmd.multiply(t)).divide(new BigDecimal(2d).multiply(new BigDecimal(Math.sqrt(Dxm3d.multiply(R).multiply(t).doubleValue()))), RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN));
System.out.println("value segundoTermo " + segundoTermo);
```

**Value returned**

```
valor do segundo termo pfv:6.31838147917065306052600332590254032941338413886611227745342947009953030493273342105799365116070956364
```

**Expected Value**

```
6,321092458
```

Comment: I get the same answer with java and wolfram-mathematica. Where are you getting the expected value from?

Answer (score 1):

I said:

> I'm betting the difference you're seeing is due to the Math.sqrt()
>   call which takes a double. You might take a look at [JScience](http://jscience.org/api/index.html) and
>   [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756021/90313).

But ends up that using JScience's FloatingPoint returns the same value as BigDecimal from the question:

```
FloatingPoint R = FloatingPoint.valueOf(2.79E+00);
FloatingPoint Dxm3d = FloatingPoint.valueOf(3.99E-04);
FloatingPoint Wmd = FloatingPoint.valueOf(2.39E-03);
FloatingPoint x = FloatingPoint.valueOf(3.2);
FloatingPoint t = FloatingPoint.valueOf(365);
FloatingPoint segundoTermo = (R.times(x).minus(Wmd.times(t)).divide(FloatingPoint.valueOf(2d).times(((Dxm3d.times(R).times(t)).sqrt()))));
System.out.println("value segundoTermo " + segundoTermo);
```

outputs:

```
value segundoTermo 0.63188145784374107900E1
```

Are you sure the expected value is correct?

Comment: yes is correct could reach the correct result. check here: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105192/aumentar-precis%C3%A3o-com-bigdecimal-java